# Finding similar products using LSH on structured data

Tags: hash, apache-spark, similarity, recommendation-engine, locality-sensitive-hash

I am trying to build a similar product using LSH and I have following query.

My data has following schema

```
id: long,
title: string,
description: string,
category: string,
price: double,
inventory_count: int,
active: boolean,
date_added: datetime
```

**Should I perform LSH on individual features separately and then combine them in some way, may be weighted average?**

or

**Should I go about building LSH on all features all together (basically attaching feature name while creating shingles like title_iphone, title_nexus, price_1200.25, active_1...) and then using bag-of-words approach perform LSH on this bag?**

If someone can direct me to a document where I can figure out how to perform LSH on structured data like of ecommerce it will be great.

P.S. I'm planning to use spark and min-hash function in LSH. Let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with your first approach but concatenate the binary codes we obtained from each individual LSH-hash instead of averaging them.

For instance, suppose you use 4 bits to represent the hash ( for each feature family) :

```
data_0:
hash(id) 0101
hash(title) 1001
hash(date_added) 0001
hash(data_0) = 0101,1001,0001
weighted_average = (5+9+1)/3 = 15/3 = 5
```

Now suppose your have another hash for `data_1`:

```
hash(data_1) = 111100000000
weighted_average = (15+0+0)/3= 15/3 = 5
```

In your retrieval process, the similarity search could be performed by first compute the hash for the query data: for instance,

```
hash(data_x) = 010010000011
weighted_average = (4+8+3)/3 = 15/3 = 5
```

Suppose you found out that `data_1` and `data_0` are the only two data pieces that have been hashed to the same bucket as `data_x`, then you only need to compute the hamming distance (which can be calculated
using bitwise operator XOR) between

- `data_1` and `data_x` -> hamming distance = 6, similarity = 6/12
- `data_0` and `data_x` -> hamming distance = 3, similarity = 9/12

So in this example, `data_0` is the most similar data to your query.

NOTE you will lose the similarity info encoded in individual binary codes if you average them. See the examples above, you would get the same encoding for `data_1` and `data_0`, which is 5 or 1001. However, if you look at each individual feature, apparently `data_1` is more different from `data_x` than `data_0`.

ALSO NOTE If you feel some feature family is more important thus it worths more weight, you can use more bits for that feature family.